# What's the reason for returning the fetch in the redux reddit api example?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

In the react-redux api example in the following code after the dispatch there's a return.

see here:

http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/ExampleRedditAPI.html

```
function fetchPosts(subreddit) {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(requestPosts(subreddit))
    return fetch(`https://www.reddit.com/r/${subreddit}.json`) //This Return
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => dispatch(receivePosts(subreddit, json)))
  }
}
```

I was wondering what's the benefit of that return if there is any?

Why not do something like the following:

```
export function hydrateStore (store) {
  return dispatch => {
    fetch(someEndPoint) //We don't return
      .then(items => items.json())
      .then(payload => {
        // do stuff
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
      })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first example returns a Promise so it can be awaited. The second example will never return anything so you can't await the dispatch to complete in the calling code before proceeding.

So essentially, first one allows you to have better control of asynchronous operation.